# creating new column based on values from 2 other data frames

Tags: r, merge

I want to create a df that combines elements from 2 columns in other dfs.

Below is df1:

```
id visit v1
1   4    25
1   5    23
2   1    8
```

Below is df2:

```
id visit v2
1   3    11
1   4    5
2   1    9
```

I want:

```
id visit v1  v2
1   3    NA  11
1   4    25   5
1   5    23  NA
2   1    8    9
```

I tried this

```
df3 <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
 group_by(id, visit) %>%
 distinct() %>%
 arrange(id, visit)
```

But it's not doing an exact merge on id and visit. See snipbit below where participant 1 and visit 4 is not merging.

```
id visit v1  v2
1   3    NA  11
1   4    25   NA
1   4    NA   5
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: @akrun, that doesn't do what I need it to do.

Comment: WIth your new dataset `full_join(df1, df2)` is working for me

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. I just updated my question. I'm having the issue that I pointed out in the last part of my comment where it isn't merging by id and visit correctly.

Comment: Please check the `full_join` which is working with the new example

Comment: Yes, full_join worked! Thank you @akrun! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
full_join(df1, df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base syntax:

```
df1 <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,2,3,3), c(4,5,1,1,2)))
names(df1) <- c("id", "visit")

df2 <- data.frame(cbind(c(1,1,2,3,3), c(3,4,1,3,4)))
names(df2) <- c("id", "visit")

merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = c("id", "visit"), all = TRUE)
```

Great post on joins [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)